# Django after login why the request.user is always anonymous?

Tags: django

***I want to redirect a homepage after login in, but the request.user is always anonymous.Where the errors hide?***

the code:
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^login/$', login_view),
        url(r'^main/$', main_view,name='main'),
    )
```

i have a login form named forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,
            label='',
            max_length=12,
            error_messages={'required':'username'},
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder':'username',
                       'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True,
            label='',
            max_length=12,
            min_length=6,
            error_messages={'required':'password'},
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder':'password',
                       'class':'form-control'}))

    def clean(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError('username and password are required')
        else:
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
```

**the view file:**

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':  
        form = LoginForm(auto_id=False)  
        return render_to_response('game/login.html',
                RequestContext(request, {'form': form,}))
    else:  
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')  
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')  
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username,
                                     password=password)  
            if user is not None and user.is_active:  
                auth.login(request, user)  
                return render_to_response('game/main.html',
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:  
                return render_to_response('game/login.html',
                    RequestContext(request, 
                        {'form': form,'password_is_wrong':True}))  
        else:  
            return render_to_response('weapon/login.html',
                    RequestContext(request, {'form': form,}))  

@login_required(login_url='/game/login/')
def main_view(request):
    user = request.user
    return render_to_response('weapon/main.html',
                     {'user':user},
                     context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

login.html include:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="{% url 'game:main'  %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login in</h2>
         {{ form.as_p }} 
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
```

main.html include:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.username }} Successful
{% else %}
    failed
{% endif %}  
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: actually i have the same problem, did u figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After login you are redirecting the user to `game/main.html` whereas in my opinion you should redirect user to `main_view` instead.

The code block in `views.py` should be:-

EDITED:

```
if user is not None and user.is_active:  
    auth.login(request, user)  
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/game/main')
```

Comment: edited my response, try HttpResponseRedirect instead.

Comment: if i write as below and write login_view as before, it can work without login_required,if i add login_required, it can't work right now:                                                                 def main_view(request):
     username = request.POST['username']
     user = User.objects.get(username=username)
     return render_to_response('game/main.html',
                     {'user':user},
                     context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: I think your login_url should point to a view and in that view you should check if user is already authenticated then redirect to main_view else redirect to login. Currently you are redirecting every response to some html page which will not work. Also in `login_view` every GET request is forwarded to login page, so even if user is authenticated he will see login page.

Answer (score 0):

The form in your login template is pointing to the main view `action="{% url 'game:main'  %}"` not the login view, your form never gets handled.

You should point it to the same login view to handle the authentication, simply use `action="."` too keep it on the same URL as the login view or point it specifically using the same technique you're using already with main, i.e.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^login/$', login_view, name='login'),
   url(r'^main/$', main_view, name='main'),
)
```

And in your template:

```
action="{% url 'game:login'  %}"
```